# NHibernate Hide dummy entity

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-one

I'm dealing with a legacy db, which uses dummy records for *some* empty relations.

*Example:* article has a relation to supplier. If an article has no supplier, a dummy supplier with ID 0 is assigned to the article, to satisfy the relation between both tables.

When adding a new article via nhibernate, I have to load and assign this dummy supplier to the new article. I would prefer being able to add a new article and leave the supplier field as NULL.

So I'm looking for a solution to transparently transform NULL to this dummy record and vice versa. With help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153564) I was able to do the conversion from NULL to the dummy record, but how can I hide the dummy entity in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a filter to your entities and enable the filter in your session.

[nhibernate-filters](http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters)